# Getting IO exception while creating file in Android?

Tags: android, ioexception

I am working in an application and getting very silly exception when I create file after creating folder in my SDCARD. I am working with Below code:

```
private void downloadFileFromURL(String filePath){
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "PS/BC_REPO");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file=new File(folder, "My_QR_Image.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
        boolean pdfSize=Downloader.downloadFile(QRCodeImageURL1, file, GetAllDataFromServerActivity.this);

        if(pdfSize){
            System.out.println("downloaded");
        }
    }



java.io.IOException: Not a directory
at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1160)
t com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.downloadFileFromURL(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:614)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.getJsonResponse(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:169)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.access$0(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:124)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity$1.dispatchMessage(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:108)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.serverResponse(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:103)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator.notifyRegisteredUser(WebServiceCommunicator.java:225)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator.handleResponse(WebServiceCommunicator.java:211)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator$2.run(WebServiceCommunicator.java:99)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
: W/System.err(6175): java.io.IOException: Not a directory
at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1160)
at com.tech.persociety.Downloader.downloadFile(Downloader.java:32)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.downloadFileFromURL(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:623)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.getJsonResponse(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:169)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.access$0(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:124)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity$1.dispatchMessage(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:108)
at com.tech.persociety.GetAllDataFromServerActivity.serverResponse(GetAllDataFromServerActivity.java:103)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator.notifyRegisteredUser(WebServiceCommunicator.java:225)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator.handleResponse(WebServiceCommunicator.java:211)
at com.tech.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator$2.run(WebServiceCommunicator.java:99)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I have to create a FOLDER PS inside which I have to create another folder BCREPO inside which I have to create a JPG file. But getting failed in this.

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: do you have the permission to write the external storage directory?

Comment: Yes I have the Permission. Please see I have posted the Stack Trace

Comment: I tried your code and its working well. First time I didn't add the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, so the file was not created. But when I add `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` all worked well. Check your permission, may be you might have misspelled it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to create two folders "PS/BC_REPO". Try using `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()` and check the return value. The stacktrace indicates that creating the folder did not work.

Comment: Maybe the PS directory already exists and he is just creating a sub dir?

Comment: brillenheini : I have tried with that.. but still getting expcetion

Comment: @Sam-In-TechValens Have you checked the boolean return value if creating the directories works?

Comment: @Sam-In-TechValens and with mkdirs?

Comment: Same result, even if I have reduce it to only one folder that is PS.

Comment: You can also use folder.isDirectory() to test if it already exists.

Comment: getting False by isDirectory method also.

Answer (score 0):

its your directory problem
change **"PS/BC_REPO"** to **"/PS/BC_REPO"**
change **My_QR_Image.jpg** to **/My_QR_Image.jpg**
Or also you can use the **/** after the folder name

and check again.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
returns **/mnt/sdcard** so you have to include the **/** ...

Comment: same result... still getting IOExcetpion

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File mSampleFile = null;
  if (mSampleFile == null) {

   String newFolder = "/PS/BC_REPO";

        String extStorageDirectory = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);

    if (!myNewFolder.exists()) {

    myNewFolder.mkdir();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one answer.....Now here we have folder PS in which we have one JPG file. But i want to create another folder within PS in which I have to store the file.

```
private void downloadFileFromURL(String filePath){
        String QRCodeImageURL = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("QR_CODE"); 
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "BCRepo");
        folder.mkdir();
        File file=new File(folder, "My_QR_Image.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.DIALOG_TITLE_ERROR,"Error", GetAllDataFromServerActivity.this,false);
                }
            });
        }
        boolean pdfSize=Downloader.downloadFile(QRCodeImageURL, file, GetAllDataFromServerActivity.this);
        if(pdfSize){
            System.out.println("downloaded");
        }
    }
```